# Unable to set foreign key for my computed column

Tags: sql

I can't set the foreign key for my advertisement table or should I say how do I add datatype for my computed column in employer table ? error details below

```
CREATE Table Employer
( 
    No Int  NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    EmployerID AS 'EID'+ CAST(No as VARCHAR(50)) PERSISTED NOT NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT PK_Employer PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(EmployerID),
    EUsername CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    EPassword CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Contact_Number INT NOT NULL,
    Email CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Company_Name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Current_Position VARCHAR(30) NULL
);

CREATE Table Advertisement
(
    No Int  NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    AdvertisementID AS 'AID'+ CAST(No as VARCHAR(10)) PERSISTED ,
      CONSTRAINT PK_Advertisement PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(AdvertisementID) ,
    Employer_ID VARCHAR(10) Foreign Key References Employer(EmployerID) NOT NULL,
    Company_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Company_Location CHAR(30) NULL,
    Job_Position VARCHAR(30)NOT NULL,
    Job_Description VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    Skills_Requirement VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    Education_Requirement CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Salary CHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

This is the error I keep getting :

> Msg 1753, Level 16, State 0, Line 27
>   Column 'Employer.EmployerID' is not the same length or scale as referencing column 'Advertisement.EmployerID' in foreign key 'FK__Advertise__Emplo__07C12930'. Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 27
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: I would try **not** to reference a computed column.... why can't you just make `Employer.No` the primary key and reference that column? That would save a lot of trouble!

Comment: if i do so, then wouldnt i be getting number like 1,2,3,4,5 as foreign key in the advertisement table instead of EID1, or it doesnt really matter ?

Comment: Yes, you'd have `1`, `2`, and so forth in `Advertisement` - but so what? It's just a foreign key, used to establish a link between the two tables. It's not something the end-user should ever see anyway!

Comment: oh ok, thanks alot get your point and thx for editing

Answer (score 0):

note that the foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale for both foreign key and primary key

so you must set `EmployerID` field to `varchar(50)` in `advertisement` table

Its recommended to use `BIGINT` auto increment field type for EmployerID.
and use Employer table's `EmployerID` field as you foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE [Employer](
    [EmployerID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EUsername] [char](20) NOT NULL,
    [EPassword] [char](20) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Contact_Number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Email] [char](20) NOT NULL,
    [Company_Name] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [Current_Position] [varchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [Advertisement](
    [AdvertisementID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [fk_Employer_ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Company_Name] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Company_Location] [char](30) NULL,
    [Job_Position] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Job_Description] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Skills_Requirement] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Education_Requirement] [char](50) NOT NULL,
    [Salary] [char](20) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Advertisement] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AdvertisementID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [Advertisement]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Advertisement_Employer] FOREIGN KEY([fk_Employer_ID])
REFERENCES [Employer] ([EmployerID])

ALTER TABLE [Advertisement] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Advertisement_Employer]
```