# Keep receiving Invalid column name 'Username'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i had the exact name in my database yet i still keep getting that error as titled.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Image Link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxlna.png

Additional information: Invalid column name 'Username'.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ERegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string checkuser = "select count(*)from Employer where Username='" + TextBoxELUsername.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from Employer where Username='" + TextBoxELUsername.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
            string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ","");
            if (password == TextBoxLoginPassword.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = TextBoxELUsername.Text;
                Response.Write("Password is Correct");

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Password Incorrect");

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Username Incorrect");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Does that column exist?

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: so does that field exist in your Employer table? are you sure you're using the RIGHT employer table?

Comment: Are you sure your `Employer` table has a column called `Username`? And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And don't store your passwords as a plain text.

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection.

Comment: From here there doesn't look to be a space between count(*) and from.

Comment: Show us your schema.

Comment: Also, what @SLaks said.  1,000,000 times.  Don't store passwords in plain text.

Comment: This code is a masterclass in bad security practice. Aside from the plaintext passwords, error message `Password Incorrect` tells me i have guessed a valid username.

Comment: you need space between count and from

Comment: According to [one of your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826296/unable-to-set-foreign-key-for-my-computed-column), your column is named `EUsername`. Are you sure you're connecting to the right database? And please read the other comments, this code is, frankly, a gigantic mess.

Comment: thanks everyone, learn and correct alot of my mistake and also realize alot things apart from this mistake thanks to you all, to be honest i am totally blur while doing this assignment by just following this video tutorial, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QoPABrUknsE, my course only teach sql but never teach web development, and i forced to do it for the assignment, so i just follow the tutorial above and slowly understand what u guys saying.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is invalid. You forgot a space between the `count(*)` and `from` keyword. Try this instead:

```
select count(*) from Employer where Username=
```

Also you should change your sql to not allow sql injections and use the `Parameters` object

Answer (score -1):

In the case of your Sql statement to retrieve the count(*) you really should Parameterize that statement to prevent sql injection.

```
string checkuser = @"select count(*)from Employer where Username= ?";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBoxELUsername.Text );
```

In addition try returning the variable temp in this fashion.

```
int temp = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar();
```

Beyond that I would try creating a second connection contained within the IF statement. It may sound odd but that connection can be stripped out of memory before the IF statement is triggered and in turn the program has no idea what connection your are trying to open.

You could avoid a second connection all together by creating a single sql statement

```
string checkuser = @"select count(*)from Employer where Username= ? and password = ?";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBoxELUsername.Text );
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBoxLoginPassword.Text );
```

your count return will only exist is both the username and password are correct.

You may also want to use the following code to force case sensitivity on your query

```
alter database your_database collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Comment: thanks everyone, learn and correct alot of my mistake and also realize alot things apart from this mistake thanks to you all, to be honest i am totally blur while doing this assignment by just following this video tutorial, youtube.com/watch?v=QoPABrUknsE, my course only teach sql but never teach web development, and i forced to do it for the assignment, so i just follow the tutorial above and slowly understand what u guys saying.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...